# How can I get the effect associated with a $k$-unit increase in the predictor in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

The outcome of interest is disease yes/no (coded 1/0) and the continuous variable of interest is measured in nmol/L. The output of the regression suggests that a 1 unit change in the predictor (presumably a 1 nmol/L increase) results in a 3% reduction in disease. This is significant. However, I think it would be more meaningful to consider the reduction in disease for every 10 nmol/L increase in the continuous variable. Is this possible?

Incidentally I did log transform to base 2 as per a previous suggestion and this showed that a doubling in the continuous variable resulted in a 35% reduction in disease outcome.

Comment: Certainly it's possible, and @macro has said how. But if you tell us what software you are using, we can give you exact guidance. For instance, SAS offers a UNITS option in PROC LOGISTIC that lets you do this without creating a new variable.

Comment: @Macro is exactly right here (you could also just multiply your 1-unit effect by 10 each time, but that would get tedious). Note however, that logistic regression does not afford an effect size as a constant % change. That will depend on the starting & ending %'s. Rather, LR allows you to calculate an *odds ratio* as a constant effect size. That is, the odds ratio will be the same from $X_1=1$ to $X_1=2$, as from $X_1=2$ to $X_1=3$, whereas the % change will *not*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a binary outcome $Y_i$ and a single predictor $X_i$ and fit a logistic regression model:

$$ \log \left( \frac{ P(Y_i = 1 | X_i) }{ P(Y_i = 0 | X_i) } \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i$$

Then, $e^{\beta_1}$ is the multiplicative change in odds that $Y_i=1$ associated with a 1-unit increase in the predictor. For example, $e^{\beta_1} = 1.03$ then a one unit increase in $X_i$ leads to $3\%$ increase in the odds that $Y_i = 1$.

Now, if the natural scale of $X_i$ is not of interest to you, then you can re-scale so that $e^{\beta_1}$ is the percentage change of interest. For example, if you're truly interested in the effect of a $10$-unit change in $X_i$, as you appear to be here, then $e^{10\beta_1}$ is the quantity of interest. In general, $e^{c \cdot \beta_1}$ is the change in odds associated with a $c$ unit increase in the predictor.

You can also, equivalently, scale your predictor variable before the analysis to get the same result. That is, if you instead used the predictor $X^{\star}_i = c \cdot X_i$ then the resulting regression coefficient would be interpreted as the effect for a $c$ unit increase in the original predictor, $X_i$.

Comment: +1, Note that there is an intrinsic ambiguity in "3% increase". You correctly state that this is a 3% increase *in the odds*, however the way OP's question is worded suggests they believe that it is a 3% change in the *probability*.

Comment: Thanks guys. Extremely helpful as always. I am using STATA for this particular project. I guess the same advice applies...

Comment: @gung, good point - in this case, calculating percentage change in risk on the probability scale would require calculating fitted probabilities and looking at the $\%$ change (which would certainly depend on $X_i$). If one were interested in $\%$ differences in the probability of disease, then something other than the logistic model may be more appropriate - I'm not quite sure what though - any suggestions?

Comment: @Macro, dunno... For each % difference I wanted to know about, I would just use LR, compute the predicted probabilities & subtract. I just wanted to make the distinction b/t % change in probability & odds ratio explicit, b/c it's central to LR & people are often confused about it.